# Where is \fromto defined, and can I change it?

Tags: biblatex

My research group has a shared collection of bib-files which I'm converting my thesis to use. However, these files use the `\fromto` macro to specify page ranges, and my thesis is currently set up using XeLaTeX and `fontspec` to disable all the TeX input ligatures, which interacts badly with something somewhere in `biblatex` which outputs this definition to the bbl file: `\newcommand{\fromto}[2]{#1$\,$--$\,$#2}`. This of course means that my bibliography has page ranges with two hyphens in them, which is less than ideal.

I've grepped through my texmf tree, but I'm unable to find any mention at all of `\fromto` in the entire `biblatex` tree, nor in the `bibtex` tree or the Biber sources. Is this something that can be configured through `biblatex`, or is my current solution of renewing the command after the `\begin{document}` as good a solution as I can hope for?

Comment: Yeah, it's a `@preamble` that I missed while grepping among all the uses of the macro. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to make commands available in a BibTeX database (`.bib` file) using an `@preamble` entry. This is used for example if one or more database entries use some mark-up that might not be available in a document. A common example is

```
@preamble{\providecommand\url[1]{\texttt{#1}}}
```

which is used to allow a (very limited) `\url` command in entries even if `url`/`hyperref` is not loaded.

Here, it seems that `\fromto` is set up in this way with some database entries then using it rather than a simple page range (`n-m` or `n--m`). As `biblatex` doesn't  parse for `\fromto` this is passed through to the `.bbl` file unchanged, as with any custom markup.